# remove duplates from multi lists at same index

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I know the built-in function np.unique() for removing all item duplicated in an array list in python, or convert the array list in a dict and to an array list.

But, the problem I have is the following:

I have for example 3 lists:
`l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'a', 'j', 'a'] l2 = ['b', 'a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'b', 'j', 'b'] l3 = ['c', 'a', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'c', 'j', 'c']`

I would like to know if it exists a built-in function to remove duplicates "a, b, c"
a in list l1
b in list l2
c in list l3
and  "a, b, c" are in same index
in the example, it should remove items at index 8 and 6 on the 3 lists.

thanks with your help.

I would like to know if it exists a built-in function to remove duplicates "a, b, c"
a in list l1
b in list l2
c in list l3
and  "a, b, c" are in same index
in the example, it should remove items at index 8 and 6 on the 3 lists.

thanks with your help.

Comment: `l3` also has a repeated `a` in its list. Is this a typo?

Comment: L3 can have "a" or "b" or "c" repeated, but only when at same index l1[index] == "a", l2[index] == "b" and l3[index] == "c", then it will remove if it's duplated in another index

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, each list while having different unique values, would return the same `unique_indices` and `unique_counts` when running `np.unique` on each list. We can leverage this by only running `np.unique` on one list with `return_counts` and `return_index` set to `True`, and then use its output.

```
uni, ind, cts = np.unique(l1, return_counts = True, return_index = True)
no_repeat_l1 = np.array(l1)[ind[cts == 1]]
no_repeat_l2 = np.array(l2)[ind[cts == 1]]
no_repeat_l3 = np.array(l3)[ind[cts == 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can do:

```py
l1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "a", "j", "a"]
l2 = ["b", "a", "b", "d", "e", "f", "b", "j", "b"]
l3 = ["c", "a", "a", "d", "e", "f", "c", "j", "c"]

out, found = [], False
for t in zip(l1, l2, l3):
    if t == ("a", "b", "c"):
        if found is False:
            out.append(t)
            found = True
    else:
        out.append(t)

l1, l2, l3 = map(list, zip(*out))
print(f"{l1=}\n{l2=}\n{l3=}")
```

Prints:

```
l1=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'j']
l2=['b', 'a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'j']
l3=['c', 'a', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'j']
```